# memory/pointer behavior for self = [super init]

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management, self

Forgiveness, please: I am a beginner. I was looking at another quesiton/answer and came across this code:

```
SpinningView *spinner = [[SpinningView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)]
```

//  Now let's take a look at the implementation of SpinningView's -initWithFrame: method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I believe that, in the second section of code, self points to the instance to which the message was sent that resulted in "self" being encountered, i.e., the result of [SpinningView alloc]. (Or doesn't that produce an instance?)

So, when you call self = [super initWithFrame:frame] on the 4th line of code, are you not reassigning the pointer value associated with "spinner"? I.e, are you not abandoning the memory you allocated in the first line? Or does the compiler someone know just to copy memory values instead of changing the pointer value? Or... what??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KevinBallard covered most of the points. The reason we need the `self =` is because `init` is not guaranteed to return the same object it is called on (it could return a different object or `nil`). I will answer your questions and expand on the memory management aspects:

> I believe that, in the second section of code, self points to the
>   instance to which the message was sent that resulted in "self" being
>   encountered, i.e., the result of [SpinningView alloc].

Yes

> So, when you call self = [super initWithFrame:frame] on the 4th line
>   of code, are you not reassigning the pointer value associated with
>   "spinner"?

Yes. Not `spinner` (`spinner` doesn't exist at this point anyway). You are re-assigning the pointer variable`self` inside the method.

> I.e, are you not abandoning the memory you allocated in the first
>   line? Or does the compiler someone know just to copy memory values
>   instead of changing the pointer value? Or... what??

Yes. Under MRC, you are just re-assigning the pointer, and the compiler does not do anything except change the pointer value. Under ARC, it's more complicated, but at the end of the day, the compiler just does the same as under MRC in this case, i.e. just re-assigns the pointer.

It's not really "abandoning" the memory if you think about it. You see, by convention, `init` methods take ownership of ("consume") an already-retained object that they're called on (usually the return result of a call to `alloc`), and they return a retained object. But these two don't have to be the same object. So when your `init` method is called, its `self` is already retained, and the `init` method owns it, but then it calls `[super init...]`, which calls the superclass's `init` method on `self`, so that method now *takes ownership* of the `self` which your `init` had ownership to. And in return, that superclass's `init` returns back to you a retained instance, which you assign to `self`. You did not "abandon" `self` because you gave it to the superclass's `init` method, which in turn became responsible for memory managing it (including releasing it if it wants to return something else).

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard idiom for the `-init` method of obj-c objects. The idea being that, whatever was allocated from `+alloc` doesn't matter, only what was returned from `-init` matters. Now, `-init` will *usually* just use the already-allocated object that's in `self`. But it's not required to. It is free to deallocate that object and create a new one. The classic example is when you alloc/init an `NSString*` you don't actually get back an instance of `NSString*`, you get back a concrete subclass. This is because `NSString*` is a "class cluster". So when you call `+alloc` you get back an `NSString*`, but when you call `-init` it frees that object and reallocates an object of one of its subclasses, initializes that new object, and hands it back to you.

Another example would be if you had a class that tried to memoize itself. Lets say you have an immutable class that gets initialized with a number. You could change your `-init` to re-use existing instances of the class. Here's an example (note: not thread-safe):

```
static NSDictionary *numberCache;

@interface MyNumber : NSObject
@property (readonly) int number;
- (id)initWithInt:(int)i;
@end

@implementation MyNumber
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [MyNumber class]) {
        numberCache = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}

- (id)initWithInt:(int)i {
    // find ourself in the numberCache
    NSValue *val = [numberCache objectForKey:@(i)];
    if (val) {
        // yep, we exist. Release the just-allocated object
        [self release];
        // and retain the memoized object and stuff it back in self
        self = [[val nonretainedObjectValue] retain];
    } else if ((self = [super init])) {
        // nope, doesn't exist yet. Initialize ourself
        _number = i;
        // and stuff us into the cache
        val = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self];
        [numberCache setObject:val forKey:@(i)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // remove us from the cache
    [numberCache removeObjectForKey:@(_number)];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `init` causing the `alloc`'d instance to be freed :S It looks like it's using something like the flyweight pattern, at least that's what my outputs are showing.

Comment: @Paul.s: In the code I posted, that's the `[self release]` before assignment to self.

Comment: @Paul.s: In the code in your example, if `[super initWithFrame:frame]` returned something other than the existing value of `self`, it will have already released the old value.

Comment: I think you have me confused for the OP. I was talking specifically about the class cluster example of `NSString` you used. In my tests `NSLog(@"%d", [NSString alloc] == [NSString alloc]); //=> 1`, which suggests to me that the intermediary `NSPlaceholderString` is not being freed but is just a flyweight.

Comment: @Paul.s: So I did. I don't pay much attention to names. And yeah, `[NSString alloc]` almost certainly does just return a singleton placeholder. It's a simple enough optimization.